# Filters in a horizontal scroll or in a dropdown; what is better? (i made an example image)

Tags: mobile, filter, web, portfolio

I had some discussion with a coworker over what is better.
in total 3 or 4 filter items

Would love the know what you think about this.

[image: Text]

Answer (score 1):

I like the horizontal one more since it's give at least some context for other available options. I would consider the option to select multiple filters at once tho. Especially if there is not many possible filters it can be beneficial to swap between different combinations.

[image: an outlined filter chip]

https://material.io/components/chips#filter-chips

Answer (score 0):

I would like the horizontal one.

Sliding fingers on the screen is a much easier gesture than tapping on a small tappable area. There is a lesser risk of failure to that action. Plus, when multiple filters are selected, they all are visible together in one go, which helps user a great deal.